# Instantsearch not working with React - Data not displaying

Tags: reactjs, meilisearch, instantsearch

I have my instantsearch which is working perfectly fine when i run it as is as shown below

[image]

However, when I tried to integrate it wit router dom, it seems something on the router dom is causing my instantsearch results to not be rendered. my instant search is being deployed inside the

```
App.js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./pages";
import HiringHomePage from "./pages/hiring";
import TelentHomePage from "./pages/telent";




const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        {/* Routes from telent */}
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/telent" element={<TelentHomePage />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/telent/findwork" element={<TelentHomePage />} />
        {/* Routes for hiring */}
        <Route path="/dashboard/hire" element={<HiringHomePage />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/hire/discover" element={<HiringHomePage />}/>
        <Route path="/dashboard/hire/discover/profile-description" element={<HiringHomePage />}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
```

Discover.js

```
import "instantsearch.css/themes/algolia-min.css";
import instantsearch from 'instantsearch.js';
import {
  InstantSearch,
  Hits,
  SortBy,
  SearchBox,
  Pagination,
  Highlight,
  ClearRefinements,
  RefinementList,
  Configure,
  Snippet
} from "react-instantsearch-dom";
import { instantMeiliSearch } from '@meilisearch/instant-meilisearch';
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';

const searchClient = instantMeiliSearch(
  "xxx",
  "xxx"
);


const Discover = () => (
  <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName="gurucool_dev">
    <SearchBox />
    <Hits />
  </InstantSearch>
);




export default Discover;
```

Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: please provide a https://codesandbox.io/ link...

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve it. This is the right code.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);
createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App> App</App>)


reportWebVitals();
```

Formerly it was

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. 
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Isn't this one only removing strict mode? Also, did you get any kind of error on that one with the previous code?